# Tengo problema con mi repositorio de UBuntu 19.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al intentar actualizar los repositorio desde mi terminal me encuentro con este error

Comment: Puede intentar este: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 (fuente: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1636513.html)

Comment: nada presento el mismo problema, misma clave